# Filter Dataframe with a list of time ranges

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, dataframe

below is a simplified version of my setup:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt

df_data = pd.DataFrame({'DateTime' : [dt.datetime(2017, 9, 1, 0, 0, 0),dt.datetime(2017, 9, 1, 1, 0, 0),dt.datetime(2017, 9, 1, 2, 0, 0),dt.datetime(2017, 9, 1, 3, 0, 0)], 'Data' : [1,2,3,5]})

df_timeRanges = pd.DataFrame({'startTime':[dt.datetime(2017, 8, 30, 0, 0, 0), dt.datetime(2017, 9, 1, 1, 30, 0)], 'endTime':[dt.datetime(2017, 9, 1, 0, 30, 0), dt.datetime(2017, 9, 1, 2, 30, 0)]})

print df_data
print df_timeRanges
```

This gives:

```
   Data            DateTime
0     1 2017-09-01 00:00:00
1     2 2017-09-01 01:00:00
2     3 2017-09-01 02:00:00
3     5 2017-09-01 03:00:00
              endTime           startTime
0 2017-09-01 00:30:00 2017-08-30 00:00:00
1 2017-09-01 02:30:00 2017-09-01 01:30:00
```

I would like to filter `df_data` with `df_timeRanges`, with the remaining rows in a single dataframe, kind of like:

```
df_data_filt = df_data[(df_data['DateTime'] >= df_timeRanges['startTime']) & (df_data['DateTime'] <= df_timeRanges['endTime'])]
```

I did not expect the above line to work, and it returned this error:

```
ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects
```

Would anyone be able to provide some tips on this? The `df_data` and `df_timeRanges` in my real task are much bigger.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is `DateTime` in `df_data` unique?

Comment: Yes, all three time fields are unique, and none of the time ranges overlap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUIC, Use

```
In [794]: mask = np.logical_or.reduce([
             (df_data.DateTime >= x.startTime) & (df_data.DateTime <= x.endTime) 
             for i, x in df_timeRanges.iterrows()])

In [795]: df_data[mask]
Out[795]:
   Data            DateTime
0     1 2017-09-01 00:00:00
2     3 2017-09-01 02:00:00
```

Or, also

```
In [807]: func = lambda x: (df_data.DateTime >= x.startTime) & (df_data.DateTime <= x.endTime)

In [808]: df_data[df_timeRanges.apply(func, axis=1).any()]
Out[808]:
   Data            DateTime
0     1 2017-09-01 00:00:00
2     3 2017-09-01 02:00:00
```