# Lambda function doesn't recognize variable

Tags: python, lambda, nameerror

I'm trying to run this code within a debugger on a server: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46294435

```py
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt

df_data = pd.DataFrame({'DateTime' : [dt.datetime(2017, 9, 1, 0, 0, 0),dt.datetime(2017, 9, 1, 1, 0, 0),dt.datetime(2017, 9, 1, 2, 0, 0),dt.datetime(2017, 9, 1, 3, 0, 0)], 'Data' : [1,2,3,5]})

df_timeRanges = pd.DataFrame({'startTime':[dt.datetime(2017, 8, 30, 0, 0, 0), dt.datetime(2017, 9, 1, 1, 30, 0)], 'endTime':[dt.datetime(2017, 9, 1, 0, 30, 0), dt.datetime(2017, 9, 1, 2, 30, 0)]})

print(df_data)
print(df_timeRanges)

func = lambda x: (df_data.DateTime >= x.startTime) & (df_data.DateTime <= x.endTime)

sol = df_data[df_timeRanges.apply(func, axis=1).any()]

print(sol)
```

I tested it on an online compiler and it works well https://www.online-python.com/gKUbw5OT7i

However, when I run it on a server through a python debugger (pdb), it doesn't seem to recognize the variable.

[Image: pdb returns "*** NameError: name 'df_data' is not defined"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1YTHo.png)

What can I do to fix it? What steps can I take to debug this issue?

Comment: Well, the code is certainly executable within VSCode and directly (command line) so my guess is that it's something odd about pdb. Having said that, use of lambda like that is not usual. Just make it a function and if pdb is where the problem lies, then that should solve it

Comment: Cannot reproduce; the posted code does not raise a `NameError`.

Comment: Haven't been able to reproduce this locally. Can you provide more information about how you're entering the debugger?

Comment: @Forensic_07 I'm entering it with `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()`

Comment: Right after the `print(df_timeRanges)` line?

Comment: Yes @Forensic_07

Comment: I also had this happen in an interactive IPython session, started via `embed()`. Sadly I don't have a solution.

Answer (score 0):

few workarounds are presented in https://bugs.python.org/issue26072

- using `globals()['df_data']`
- adding extra (defaulted) param to lambda: `lambda x, df_data=df_data: ...`